# Calculating coordinates of a point in new coordinate system

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**Original question:** Distance between two points A and B is known in coordinate system C1 (Δx is distance on x axis and Δy is distance on y axis of the coordinate system C1). Coordinate system C2 is rotated α degrees compared to system C1. Coordinates of point A are known in coordinate system C2. What are the coordinates of point B in system C2?

**Real life application:** I know how far away object (point B) is from AR marker (point A) - distance is given in global fixed coordinate system C1. Robot can measure how far away AR marker is from its center forming the coordinate system C2. I want to know the position of the object compared to robot's center to be able to move the gripper to the correct position.

**Additional information:**
Individual values of Δx and Δy between the AR marker (A) and object (B) are are known, where Δx = xb - xa, and Δy = yb - ya.
Individual values of xa(c2) and ya(c2) are known for AR marker (A) in coordinate system of the robot (C1).
Angle between robot center and coordinate center C1 is known (α). Angle between robot center and AR marker center is also known if required.

[Picture with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc0NA.png)

**What I tried:**
If there is no rotation I assume xb(c2) = xa(c2) + Δx and yb(c2) = ya(c2) + Δy. I tried drawing versions where C2 is rotated π and π/2 and I found what would their formulas be. However, I'm still not sure how to find general formula.

Comment: Start with something simple. Ignore the rotation first. Without the rotation, how would you obtain the inverse transform? After that, include the rotation ...

Comment: You should probably include what you have tried so far.

Comment: So all we are given is the distance $AB$ and the positions of $A$ in a single coordinate system. I think this problem does not have enough information to solve.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you know. When you say you know the distance from $A$ to $B$ we understand that you know the result of the formula $\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$. Do you actually know the individual values of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$? When you say the robot can measure the distance from its center to $A$, do you mean individual $x$ and $y$ components of distance or just the total straight line distance? Is the robot facing point $A$, does it have some other known facing direction, or do you not know which way it is facing? A picture with labels might help.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you basically want to rotate points (i.e. you know the coordinates of a point and want to calculate the coordinates of the rotated point): If your original point has coordinates $(x,y)$, the rotated point (rotated by angle $\varphi$ counter-clockwise) has coordinates $(x\cos\varphi-y\sin\varphi, x\sin\varphi+y\cos\varphi)$.